# Problem with setting up API connection with AWS Amplify

Tags: react-native, aws-amplify, flutter-aws-amplify

I am currently developing an eCommerce App in React Native Expo that utilizes AWS amplify and I am trying to connect the API and database to it.

After running 'amplify push', I get the following error message:

> � An error occurred during the push operation: Unknown directive 'connection'. Either remove the directive from the schema or add a transformer to handle it.

For some reason, it doesn't recognize @connection as its own directive.

The block of code in the schema.graphql that utilizes this directive is the following:

```
type CartProduct @model @auth(rules: [{allow: public}]){
    id: ID!
    userSub: String!
    quantity: Int!
    option: String
    productID: ID!
    product: Product @connection(fields: ["productID"])
}
```

I haven't found a solution anywhere and I appreciate anyone who can help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

[This github issue](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/9082) in the aws-amplify repo helped me solve a similar error. The gist of the problem is the graphql transformer version that interprets the schema definition was [upgraded to v2](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/aws-amplify-announces-the-new-graphql-transformer-v2-more-feature-rich-flexible-and-extensible/) and the @key and @connection directives are in a version 1 directives.

For version 2 I used @hasMany and @hasOne directives.

```
type PurchaseOrder @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner }]) {
  id: ID!
  poNumber: String
  dateOrdered: AWSDateTime
  dateRequested: AWSDateTime
  dateReceived: AWSDateTime
  notes: String
  subtotal: Float
  taxRate: Float
  salesTax: Float
  priceAdjustment: Float
  discount: Float
  total: Float
  requestor: String
  paymentTerms: String
  shipping: Float
  comments: String
  billingAddress: Address @hasOne
  shippingAddress: Address @hasOne
  shippingInformation: String
  customerId: String
  createdAt: AWSDateTime!
  updatedAt: AWSDateTime!
  poItems: [PoItem] @hasMany
  attachments: [Attachment] @hasMany
  vendorID: ID!
  vendor: Vendor @hasOne
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I think I have to study more of GraphQL directives and then give this a try.