# Unknown directive "connection" -- AWS Appsync graphql

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I'm using AWS Appsync graphql api.

Here's my schema:

```
type Project @model {
  id: ID!
  name: String
  team: Team @connection
}

type Team @model {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
}
```

when I run `amplify push` or `amplify update api`
I get this error **Unknown directive "connection".**

Error log from `amplify update api`

```sh
 Unknown directive "connection".
Error: Unknown directive "connection".
    at assertValidSDL (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/graphql/validation/validate.js:108:11)
    at buildASTSchema (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/graphql/utilities/buildASTSchema.js:71:34)
    at validateModelSchema (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/@aws-amplify/graphql-transformer-core/src/transformation/validation.ts:145:32)
    at GraphQLTransform.transform (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/@aws-amplify/graphql-transformer-core/src/transformation/transform.ts:172:39)
    at _buildProject (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/amplify-provider-awscloudformation/src/graphql-transformer/transform-graphql-schema.ts:564:37)
    at buildAPIProject (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/amplify-provider-awscloudformation/src/graphql-transformer/transform-graphql-schema.ts:521:24)
    at transformGraphQLSchema (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/amplify-provider-awscloudformation/src/graphql-transformer/transform-graphql-schema.ts:394:29)
    at CfnApiArtifactHandler.updateArtifacts (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/@aws-amplify/amplify-category-api/src/provider-utils/awscloudformation/cfn-api-artifact-handler.ts:133:7)
    at Object.executeAmplifyCommand (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/@aws-amplify/amplify-category-api/src/index.ts:222:5)
    at executePluginModuleCommand (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/src/execution-manager.ts:204:3)
    at executeCommand (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/src/execution-manager.ts:30:5)
    at Object.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/src/index.ts:205:5)
```

Please let me know if any other info is required? I'll edit the question.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've added the logs

Comment: does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70104646/problem-with-setting-up-api-connection-with-aws-amplify help?

Comment: Damn... I just came here to add the answer. I didn't know the answer already exists. Thanks a lot @SurajRao for your time and concern.